# MySql filter result list

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have this MySql query:

```
SELECT o.orders_id
FROM orders o
    LEFT JOIN orders_status_history h
    ON o.orders_status = h.orders_status_id
WHERE o.orders_status = 23
```

That's working so far.

Now - in the table "orders_status_history" there are multiple entries matching the ON-criterium (an order has different order_status values in it's history).

I only want to have the row included if it ever had a "h.orders_status_id" of 33 - meaning one of the hits in the result list of the suiting "h.orders_status_id"'s has to be 33.

I have no idea on how to get that done.
I think I need something like a filter on the result list maybe...

Comment: Could you provide table description, some insert datas and expected result ?

Comment: I dont get it - You wll have the result only when o.orders_status = 33 because o.orders_status = h.orders_status_id

Comment: Code says 23, text says 33. PS [mre] [ask] [help]

Answer (score -1):

Can you show `orders` and `orders_status_history` tables structure?:)
If your `orders_status_history` table has a row like `order_id` you can do this:

```
SELECT o.orders_id
FROM orders o
    INNER JOIN orders_status_history h
    ON o.id = h.order_id
WHERE h.id = 33
```